# Send JSON from php processing to public coldfusion page

Tags: php, json, coldfusion

I am modifying someones existing coldfusion web app.  I am adding php processing pages to do various tasks.  Up to this point I have just been calling the php pages, and interacting with the web app by passing variables via the url.

Current usage:

```
public.cfm calls processing.php?id=69
```

Then processing will do what it has too, then ultimately:

```
header("Location: $publichome?id=$id&importantstuff=$stuff");
exit();
```

And the webapp will pick up where it has too.  But now one of my scripts has to send a JSON object back instead of simple variables.  I don't know how to get this done.  I tried doing a post with cURL but that wasn't working because I need the public facing coldfusion page to take over and curl returns to the php script (I know I can echo the body of the curl result but this keeps me on the php script domain which I dont want).  Is there a way to do the above header location and send an object because thats what I need - the php script to stop and the coldfusion page to be served up with the object to work with.

Do I have to create some sort of JSON service in php, that the coldfusion page will call an retrieve the result?  I can also modify the coldfusion page any way I want.

Comment: I have thought about storing the JSON in a DB, but it may contain thousands of items so that seems like a terrible idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to pass the json string as a URL variable, just like you are passing simpler strings, through the location header.  You will need some means of json-serializing the object in php, if you haven't done that yet.  There is likely a json library available to do that.

*edit*
Based on more information, I now have a better suggestion:

From CF, make a <cfhttp> request to your PHP code, passing whatever parameters are necessary to PHP as arguments in cfhttp.  From PHP, simply "output" the JSON as the response body.  After the CFHTTP call returns to CF, you'll have access to the JSON via the cfhttp.fileContent variable, which you can then run through DeserializeJSON to get back a real object.  Here some sample CF code:

```
<cfhttp url="processing.php?id=69" method="get"></cfhttp>
<cfset importantStuff=DeserializeJSON(cfhttp.fileContent)>
```

Comment: Even know there may be thousands of items in my JSON object?  Can you provide some code?

Comment: Ah, in that case, no.  Do you have access to modify the cf code? The json needs to be sent as post data (form scope).  This can be done from either the browser (introducing a new page in the process that includes a form with a hidden field with the json value) or from php.  If from php, you could include a call to cf that contains the json before your location redirect.  This could be tricky, though, depending on your need to keep the json associated with a given user's session.  If that's the case, let me know and I can elaborate.

Comment: Yes I can modify the coldfusion page any way I want.  All my session management is done on the CF side.  Basically I start in CF then call php processing pages with some user data in the url for proper processing.  Then the php generates JSON and I have to get back to the public facing CF with that data.  Please elaborate.

Comment: You mean "output the JSON" in php just by something like: echo $myencodedjson; ??

Comment: yes, just like if you were returning the json to the browser in a direct request.